# Why do I keep receiving the "Can't find this Symbol" error each time I try to import my linked list

Tags: java

I have my two files in which I'm trying to work with, one is my own made linked list which has the iterator method which iterates over the entire linked list accessing every element. The second file is composed of extra function one of which is using this linked list class. I can import the linked list just fine however when I try to execute the Iterator I keep getting the can't find this symbol error for the Iterator. Could somebody please give me a hand.

My linked list code

```
public class DSALinkedList implements Iterable, Serializable
{
    private DSAListNode head;
    private DSAListNode tail;

    public Iterator iterator()
    {
        return new DSALinkedListIterator(this);
    }
 
    public DSALinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }
  
    public void insertFirst(Object newValue)
    ... And a lot more
```

The error code I get says

```
functions.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        Iterator iter = list.iterator();
        ^
  symbol:   class Iterator
  location: class functions
1 error
```

And the extra file in which this error is occurring is in

```
    public static void tradePaths(String base, String quote, DSAGraph graph)
    {
        DSALinkedList list = null;
        DSALinkedList tradePath = null;

        DSAGraph.DSAGraphVertex vertex = graph.getVertex(base);

        list = graph.getAdjacent(base);
        Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    }
```

Comment: Note that you're _also_ getting a lot of warnings about raw types; you should pay attention to those.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that it doesn't know the class Iterator.
You are required to

```
import java.util.Iterator
```

at beginning of this file

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't spot that thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the library package 
just enter

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

at the beginning of your code

Comment: I juts tried that and it worked perfectly, thank you.